# Transit visa for Italy when going to Germany

Tags: uk, schengen, transit-visas, italy, iraq

I want to travel to Germany, I'm Iraqi and live in UK with valid UK residence and Valid UK travel document. I found Ryanair has good price to travel to Germany. According to the list of countries that accept UK travel document without visa, Germany is OK. The thing that makes me worry is that Ryanair has a stop in Italy and I don't have transit visa for Italy. I read on the internet that Italy authorities have said if you have UK residence you may be exempt from an airport transit visa.

Note that Iraq nationality has been put in Italian list for required visa transit but in same time I have a UK travel document and valid resdince. Can anyone answer if Ryanair will accept me for going to Germany with no transit visa for Italy?

Comment: In Covid times it is so much easier if you take direct flights, it should be worth paying a lot more for the tickets. Traveling via Italy brings visa problems, risk on missed and cancelled flights.

Comment: @Anders Even with one ticket, the OP will be entering the Schengen Area in Italy.

Comment: Italy [also does not require a visa](https://conslondra.esteri.it/consolato_londra/it/i_servizi/per_chi_si_reca_in_italia/uk-travel-document.html) for holders of UK-issued travel documents

Comment: @mlc that sounds like an answer.

Comment: The airport transit visa is not relevant here, since you will be processed into the Schengen area in Italy, and airport transit visas do not authorize the bearer to pass through border controls.  If you need a visa to enter Italy, it has to be a regular short-stay visa.

Comment: Ryanair normally does not sell tickets with a stopover. Is this booked directly with them? Hopefully you did not book something with Kiwi.com...

Answer (score 3):

Based on the link (quoted below) supplied by @mlc, Italy does not require a visa to enter for a UK Travel Document (Blue or Red) holder.

Therefore you can fly to Italy, where you will enter the Schengen Area and then take an **internal** Schengen flight to Germany.

---

> [UK Travel Document - Consolato Generale d'Italia Londra](https://conslondra.esteri.it/consolato_londra/it/i_servizi/per_chi_si_reca_in_italia/uk-travel-document.html).
> **Holders of 1951 Geneva Refugee Convention Travel Document (Blue)** and **Holders of 1954 UN Convention Travel Document for Stateless (Red)** issued in Great Britain can travel visa free up to 90 days. For trips longer than 90 days, they are required to apply for long stay visas.

Answer (score -2):

Italy and Germany are both in the Schengen Zone: Italy has no authority to require visa for certain nationalities, while for COVID-19 pandemics there can be provisions for additional screening or or flight ban from origin (which is not your case, as the flight is scheduled).

Once you cross the Italian border you are crossing the general Schengen border, so the same rules apply to all Member States.

If you are sure that you can visit Germany, you can cross the Italian border.

### About transit visa

Since flights from Italy to Germany are **domestic**, and the same applies to all intra-Schengen flights, there is no such transit visa for passengers directed to a Schengen State. You clear the border only once.

Comment: "...the same rules apply to all Member States.

If you are sure that you can visit Germany, you can cross the Italian border."  That isn't necessarily true for people with refugee travel documents.  Visa exemptions for such people are governed by national law.  If Italy requires a visa then the traveler will need a visa, even if Germany does not.